# Firestore need double nested table

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So the thing is to do the table with the following logic:

```
Collection -> Document -> Collection -> Map_with_values
```

Now it is only possible to make:

Collection -> Document -> Collection -> **Document ->** Map_with_values.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), the only structure that is permited is as follows:

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')
```

> How I can do that?

You cannot do that in Firestore. The only things that can be stored beneath a collection, are the documents and only the documents. So there is no way in which you can store a `Map` directly beneath a collection. A `Map`, which is also an object can only be added as a property beneath a document. That's it!

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: i was thinking about it and I thought maybe i lost any details. But now Im sure thats its impossible. So the best way is to name somehow the extra collection and than create doc